# Oracle slow query processing

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

We have two separated enviroments with Oracle Database one with version 12.1.0.2(Server1)other 12.2.0.1(Server2). Both DBs are stored in independent machines[image]

The issue is that, for example a query in Server1 takes 3 seconds and in Server2 it takes 6 seconds. This doesn't sound that bad but we access the DB through different services like IBM Cognos so we have to add the time that takes the service to perform its tasks to the total time it takes to execute the query.

The result is that for the same process in Server1 it takes seconds to complete it vs in Server2 it takes some minutes.

Do you have any ideas as to why could this happen?

Thanks

Comment: use text formated data not image

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551 and the accepted answer

Comment: Without the table definition as `create table` statements (including all indexes), the actual query (as [formatted **text**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)), the execution plan (as [formatted **text**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)) this is impossible to answer. You might also want to read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/ for an introduction on how to ask a good question regarding SQL.

Comment: Finding "what's different" is a big question.  I'd recommend starting by looking for the slowest queries on the two systems.  Find the slowest SQL with `select * from gv$sql order by elapsed_time desc;` (or ask a DBA to use AWR or ASH if you want a better analysis), and see if one specific query is causing problems.  To investigate why, start with the execution plan, which tells you the algorithms and data structures used to run the query: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id => 'sql_id from first query'));`.  You can post results here and someone may be able to help.

Comment: Btw, I'm highly skeptical of setting the parameters OPTIMIZER_INDEX_COST_ADJ  and OPTIMIZER_INDEX_CACHING.  Those parameters significantly change the default optimizer behavior, effectively telling Oracle, "my database's indexes are more than an order of magnitude faster than you might think".  Is there actually a reason why your system would run indexes faster than normal?  Most of the time when I see those parameters set it's because somebody wanted to force an index on one plan and got lazy and decided to change the entire system.  You might want to have a DBA check all your parameters.

Comment: @JonHeller these parameters are mandatory, the company that provides this software demands that the DB is set in this particular way.Thanks